# Can Google access data stored in Google Cloud Storage when using Google-managed encryption keys?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We’ve been trying to understand if Google Cloud can access data stored in Google Storage when using Google-managed encryption keys.

We want to understand if Google potentially has access to the data stored. If yes, is there a way to restrict such access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google can. No, you cannot restrict Google.

Google publishes data policy documents on its website on how/when/if they access your data. Data access is logged so that you can see such accesses. There is a process requiring approval. A Google employee cannot just poke around in your data. Similar to most legal documents, you must read the documents to understand the details and conditions.

Start with this privacy page:

[Privacy Resource Center](https://cloud.google.com/privacy)